# SimpleDateFormat.parse - ParseException

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a (String) date into Date object, but no matter what pattern I use for `SimpleDateFormat`, I simply can't make it work, I always end up with getting a ParseException.

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM, d, h:mm a", Locale.US);

String strDate = "Tue Sep, 18, 3:30 AM";
Date newDate = null;

newDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
```

The above code gives me a `Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Sep, 18, 3:30 AM"`.

I've even tried writing the string date directly into the parse method;

```
newDate = sdf.parse("Tue Sep, 18, 3:30 AM");
```

But that doesn't make any difference.

I'm cleary doing something wrong, but I just don't see where. I've read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html over and over, and tried different `SimpleDateFormat#pattern` but haven't manage to solve it.

Comment: The code doesn't throw any Exception for me.

Comment: For me two. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything should be fine with that.. Try removing the locale, sometimes that can cause strange errors depending on the environment.

Comment: I have no explanation, but it "just works" for me now, I think this might've been a problem with Dropbox syncing my folder and perhaps locking the files as NetBeans was compiling and running it.